# passar variável javascript para pegar com post em php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Boa tarde, achei inúmeras formas de passar javascript para php porém nenhuma forma deu certo. pensei em uma forma porém não sei como efetuar, vi que com ajax seria a única forma eu acho, o que pensei foi.

tenho uma informação em localstorage, eu submito via SELF (igual ao self do php que envia para a mesma página em formulário) esta informação que no caso não irá gerar refresh para uma session em php, ou seja

javascript > localstorage.getitem() -> ajax sem precisar de outro arquivo
php > session -> post do ajax

```
    <script>
    function readaccent_color() {
        var accent_color = localStorage.getItem("accent_color");
        if(accent_color) {
            //ajax sem utilizar outro arquivo, tipo self do php para enviar uma variável para o post
$.post('SELF', {}
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("accent_color", "#6A00FF"); } }
    readaccent_color();
    </script>
    <?php echo $_POST["accent_color"]; ?>
```

existe esta possibilidade?

edit

achei este código de ajax, mas ele exibe a página toda, todo o html inteiro no console, não apenas o valor do localstorage

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
function readaccent_color() {
    var accent_color = localStorage.getItem("accent_color");
    if(accent_color) {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data:  $(accent_color).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); } });

    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("accent_color", "#6A00FF"); } }
readaccent_color();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, não sei se entendi 100% sua pergunta, mas me baseando pelo título da pergunta irei te responder.

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $teste = $_POST['teste'];
    echo "PEGUEI O VALOR: $teste";
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST" id="formteste">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="teste" name="teste">
    <input type="text" value="" id="teste2" name="teste2">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
<script>
    var x = "testando";
    document.getElementById("teste").value = x;
</script>
```

Esse código joga uma variável JS para um campo hidden em HTML e pega esse valor com o PHP.

Isso resolve o seu problema?

[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zqfx-99ip)

Comment: mas ai teria eu que enviar um submit para pegar a variável? no caso, como fazer isso no ajax sem precisar lincar outro arquivo que é o padrão e no caso do segundo código, ele não pegar todo o html do meu site, só a variável, ou seja, seria melhorar aquele código ali de cima, o seu funciona, porém teria um input na página e teria que dr submit.